# Nexus One & Windows XP USB Driver

Tags: android, adb, nexus-one

I've been unable to get my Nexus One working as a development phone on Windows XP. I've got the driver (revision 3 for N1 support), I've got it installed according to the official installation guide, and the phone appears in the Device Manager just as the guide says it should.

However, adb still can't find the phone. 'adb devices', for example, returns no active devices.

Am I forgetting some basic step?

One thing I've noticed is that the driver is labeled in Windows as version 2 released November, 2009 (I need version 3 from January 2010 for N1 support). However, I've never had version 2 installed. I've used the SDK to download version 3 several times - even deleted it and redownloaded it. I've uninstalled/reinstalled the version 3 driver multiple times. It still says version 2. Is this the problem, or this something completely unrelated?

Note: The phone is working as a dev phone on Ubuntu, so I know the phone/cable/etc. are good. It's either my fault or the driver's.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update all of your softwares and drivers. Since it has been a long time ,There's a lot of updates both drivers and Android SDK.